# Toggle Visibility By Class

Tags: javascript

Hi can anyone help me please.

How can i use Toggle Visibility by class instead of a id for example.

The Button

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="toggle_visibility('trailer');">Trailer</a>
```

Then this.

```
<div class="trailer" style="display:none">{include file="trailer.tpl"}</div>
```

So how can i modify this javascript to work with classes.

```
{literal}
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function toggle_visibility(id) {
var e = document.getElementById(id);
if(e.style.display == 'block')
e.style.display = 'none';
else
e.style.display = 'block';
}
//-->
</script>                
{/literal}
```

So what would javascript by for this please help.

Comment: Uses document.getElementByClassName instead of document.getElementById

Comment: `.getElementsByClassName` (short one ‘s’)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inline:

```
<a href="#" 
 onclick="var div = document.querySelectorAll('.trailer')[0]; 
 div.style.display=div.style.display=='none'?'block':'none';return false">Trailer</a>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
  $("#link").on("click",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".trailer").toggle();
  });
});
```

Generic jQuery:

```
$(function() {
  $(".link").on("click",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("."+this.id).toggle();
  });
});
```

using

```
<a href=".." class="link" id="trailer">Toggle</a>
```

Answer (score 6):

Use getElementsByClassName

```
function toggle_visibility(className) {
    elements = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i].style.display = elements[i].style.display == 'inline' ? 'none' : 'inline';
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
function toggle_visibility(className) {
    $('.' + className).toggle();
}
```

you should use jQuery to avoid browser compatibility issues.